Using Oracle DB Thick Mode with Node 22: "NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary" error
I'm attempting to upgrade my Node.js application to Node 22, but I'm encountering issues with connecting to Oracle DB using node-oracledb in Thick Mode. The same configuration works without issues in Node 20, but with Node 22, I receive the following error:
NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary for Node.js. Please try using Thin mode.
Looked for D:\...\my-project\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb-6.6.0-win32-ia32.node, ...

Environment:

Node.js Version: 22.11.0
node-oracledb Version: 6.6.0
Oracle Instant Client: C:\oracle\instantclient_basic_windows_x64_23_5_0_24_07\instantclient_23_5
OS: Windows

Code Snippet:
Here's the relevant portion of the code where I initialize the Oracle client:
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const knex = require('knex');

const libDir = "C:\\oracle\\instantclient_basic_windows_x64_23_5_0_24_07\\instantclient_23_5";
oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir });

const client = knex({
    client: 'oracledb',
    connection: {
        user: config.oracle.user,
        password: config.oracle.password,
        connectString: config.oracle.connectionString
    },
    pool: {
        min: config.connectionPool.min,
        max: config.connectionPool.max,
        idleTimeoutMillis: config.connectionPool.idleTimeout
    },
    acquireConnectionTimeout: config.connectionPool.acquireConnectionTimeout
});

const result = await client.raw('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL');

Error Details
With Node 22, I get the following error:
Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary for Node.js. Please try using Thin mode.
Looked for D:\...\my-project\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb-6.6.0-win32-ia32.node, ...

Steps Tried

Verified the libDir path is correct and points to the Instant Client.
Confirmed that the PATH environment variable includes the path to the Oracle Instant Client.
Downgraded to Node 20 temporarily, and confirmed that this setup works without errors.

Questions

Is there a specific Instant Client version requirement for using node-oracledb in Thick Mode with Node 22?
Are there additional configurations needed in Node 22 to support Oracle DB Thick Mode?
How can I troubleshoot further to identify the root cause of the Thick Mode binary loading failure?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Did you switch from Node.js 20 to 22 before or after installing?

Yes, I was on node 20.17.0 before, and it worked. When I updated to node 22.11.0, I got the error. I deleted the node_modules and ran npm install , on node 22, and still got the error.
When I went back to node 20 it worked again. I want it to work for me also against node 22.11.0.

Give this a try - move to Node.js 22, delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and reinstall.

Thanks, I deleted them and reinstalled, it didn't help. oracledb and knex are updated to the latest version: "knex": "^3.1.0","oracledb": "^6.6.0"

Use the attribute name in the parameter:
const libDir = "C:\\oracle\\instantclient_basic_windows_x64_23_5_0_24_07\\instantclient_23_5";
oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: libDir });


It didn't help, and it's not related either, in js there is no difference between an object { libDir:libDir } and { libDir }, it's just a shortcut in the syntax
